# Postgres could not create unique index, key is duplicated

Tags: sql, postgresql, alter-table

I'm trying to add a column to a table in my Postgres 9.3 database with this seemingly simple SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE quizzes ADD COLUMN deleted BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false;
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  could not create unique index "quizzes_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(10557462) is duplicated.
```

Strangely enough, there are actually *no rows* with that id (which is the primary key, so it shouldn't have duplicates):

```
SELECT id FROM quizzes WHERE id = 10557462;
 id 
----
(0 rows)
```

In fact, it looks like that id has been skipped somehow:

```
SELECT id FROM quizzes WHERE id > 10557459 ORDER BY id LIMIT 4;
    id    
----------
 10557460
 10557461
 10557463
 10557464
(4 rows)
```

Why is this preventing me from adding a column, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't see how adding the `deleted` column could result in a unique key violation.  Are you sure that is the code that is running?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I'm typing that code at a psql prompt and pressing Enter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suspect you have pre-existing index corruption or visibility issues.

When you `ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN ... DEFAULT ...` it does a full table rewrite. This rebuilds all indexes, in the process noticing the problem on the heap.

You'll probably find that `VACUUM FULL` on the table produces the same error.

I expect that

```
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL enable_indexscan = off;
SET LOCAL enable_bitmapscan = off;
SET LOCAL enable_indexonlyscan = off; 
SELECT ctid,xmin,xmax,id FROM quizzes WHERE id = 10557462;
ROLLBACK;
```

will reveal that the tuples actually do exist.

Please first read and act on [this wiki page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption). Once you've done that, check your version. Are you running or have you ever run a PostgreSQL 9.3 version older than 9.3.9? Especially as a replica that was then promoted? If so, that likely explains it due to the known multixact bugs that were fixed there:

- [9.3.7 relnotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/release-9-3-7.html)
- [9.3.9 relnotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/release-9-3-9.html)

Otherwise, hard to say what's happening. It'd be necessary to take a look at the problem heap page(s) using `pageinspect`, at `pg_controldata` output, and possibly at the b-tree pages referring to those heap pages.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I ran the queries you suggested, and there are indeed 5 rows with id `10557462`. And according to `SELECT id, count(*) FROM quizzes GROUP BY id HAVING count(*) > 1;`, this is the only quiz with duplicates. Any other advice in addition to acting on the data corruption wiki page?

Comment: This resolves the issue for me. It forced the hidden keys and indexes out to be displayed. Just change the column names to any column on your table, then refresh the table and check the keys and indexes you will fine them there, then delete the duplicates and all will be good.

Answer (score 9):

I've accepted @Craig Ringer's answer because I never would have been able to resolve the problem without it. In case it helps anyone else, here's the exact query I used to solve the problem (luckily for me, the duplicates can be deleted):

```
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL enable_indexscan = off;
SET LOCAL enable_bitmapscan = off;
SET LOCAL enable_indexonlyscan = off; 
DELETE FROM quizzes WHERE id = 10557462;
COMMIT;
```

After that, my original query finally succeeded:

```
ALTER TABLE quizzes ADD COLUMN deleted BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false;
```

Comment: Personally, I strongly advise that you now `pg_dump` the db(s), `pg_dumpall --globals-only`, then `initdb` a replacement blank postgres instance and restore into it. I wouldn't trust that there are no other undetected problems with this one.