# UNIQUE Constraint not working? (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I altered my postgresql database table to have a unique constraint like this:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_values UNIQUE (value_one, value_two, value_three);
```

I want to not be able to post duplicate values for value_one, value_two, or value_three. So there should only ever be ONE unique value in these columns in the entire database.

But I'm still able to INSERT duplicate values in the value_one, value_two, and value_three columns.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

I have deleted all the duplicate data in the database, but get an error whenever I try to add a unique constraint to individual columns in the table.

Another thing, if I say:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_values UNIQUE (value_one, value_two, value_three);
```

I do not get an error. But if I say:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_values UNIQUE (value_one);
```

Like with just one value, I get this error:

```
could not create unique index "unique_values"
```

Comment: Please post sample data, both rows that should and rows that should not insert. Post data as [formatted text](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) or even better a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14) - **no images**.

Comment: unique constraint means that the combination of the three are unique and not individually

Comment: Thank you so much! That is the problem. When I do it individually, it says "could not create unique index..." I think because there are already duplicate values in the database. How would I add the contraint if there are already duplicates?

Comment: you search foe them as for all other duplicates and remove or change them  as for your uniqueness, may be you should make a check constraint that checks for  value in multiple columns

Comment: I deleted all the duplicates and I still get the error.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315510/postgres-could-not-create-unique-index-key-is-duplicated

Comment: What is the complete error message? Add as update to your question.

Comment: I got it working finally. I did have duplicate values without realizing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a unique constraint over three columns, that means that you cannot insert the same three values a second time. But each of these columns can contain duplicate values. For example, these three rows would satisfy the uniqueness constraint:

```
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 4)
(1, 5, 3)
```

but you would get an error if you inserted one of these triples a second time.

If you want each column to be unique, you have to define three constraints, one for each column.

Comment: I know this is the right answer. But whenever I delete the duplicate values in the database, then try to add one constraint for each column, I still get the error: could not create unique index "unique_values" do you know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: That is because there already conflicting data in the table. You will have to delete those data.

Comment: Thank you! I got it working finally. I did have duplicate values without realizing it.