# Postgres error: could not create unique index - key is duplicated but only one record with he ID exists

Tags: database, postgresql, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

As the title says, I get an error about a duplicate ID when no duplicate exists. There are multiple answers related to this question which involve searching for other records with the same ID and deleting the duplicates, this hasn't worked.
Here are extracts that contain details from the real error messages:

```
error: could not create unique index "UQ_9e4701008510bb5b9d35d19b931"
query: 'ALTER TABLE "daily_stats" ADD CONSTRAINT "UQ_9e4701008510bb5b9d35d19b931" UNIQUE ("morning_sequence_log_id")',
severity: 'ERROR',
code: '23505',
detail: 'Key (morning_sequence_log_id)=(5d482f31-4763-442a-8a00-f449d3302ac8) is duplicated.',
```

The SQL stems from running a TypeORM migration command. The same command works on a staging DB that doesn't contain the same record.

I tried searching in the DB for duplicates of the record using the method below which I found in the answer to a similar question. No duplicates were found. I also tried the method mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45317850/17903140) answer.

```
SELECT  id, count(*)
FROM completed_activity_sequences
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Directly search for that record, select * from mytable where morning_sequence_log_id='5d482f31-4763-442a-8a00-f449d3302ac8';

Comment: If the same transaction had previously inserted a duplicate of that value, then when the constraint creation errors out the inserted value will also get rolled back, leaving no visible evidence of the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm... the definition column is "morning_sequence_log_id" and your query references "id":

ALTER TABLE daily_stats ADD CONSTRAINT "UQ_9e4701008510bb5b9d35d19b931" UNIQUE (morning_sequence_log_id)';

SELECT  id, count(*)
FROM completed_activity_sequences
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(*) > 1;

This may resolve your issue, otherwise, data corruption?